# Where could I find ready template files to code(just for fun and practice)?

Tags: html, css, templates, web, ps

I am looking for some finished templates psds to practice my coding skills. Do you know any websites where I could find some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could give http://www.oswd.org a try.